# Click events not working with canvas on top of image

Tags: javascript, canvas

Placing the canvas on top of an image makes all the click events not working.
Also, making the image not selectable or draggable does not work.
How to make the click events work?

Here is the code:
**Javascript**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    console.log('a');
}, false);
```

**HTML5**

```
<section>
<img src = "http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" />
<canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

canvas{
    width:480px;
    height:640px;
    border:1px solid white;
    position:relative;
    z-index:20;
}

section{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pmht5asf/
On jsfiddle works, but in my case I need it as an inverval. Problem is that when trying it as an interval, it blocks all clicks on page and I cannot save it.

Comment: There is no need for code here. Add image, put canvas on top and add a click event. Does not work.

Comment: @GSquadron _add a click event_ To what? image or canvas?

Comment: @GSquadron Anyway you have to show your code. Otherwise your question is off-topic

Comment: @GSquadron there is always a need for code!

Comment: The click  event seems to work on jsbin.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. your question is about 2 sentences, showing no code.. but below is my best guess. Toggling z-index.

Element you want as background.

```
#elementyoudontwanttobeclickable { 
     z-index: 1;
}
```

Element you want to be clickable below.

```
#elementyouDOwanttobeclickable { 
         z-index: 2;
}
```

[Read more about z-Index](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Comment: I tried this too does not seem to work. Wait a sec I add some code.

Comment: It actually works like this, but it crashes JSfiddle when I make it as an interval. So basically is the interval blocking click events?

Comment: It's not crashing for me, and I see no links in the code either!

Comment: But likely no anyway... you have 2 elements, your trying to use canvas as background image, you have to layer the image over it..